# valid_children does not apply in IE8

Tags: configuration, internet-explorer-8, tinymce

While `valid_children: "+body[style]"` works perfectly in IE9 and other browsers, it seems that tinymce still strips the tag in IE8 (no matter if compat view is on or not). Are there any known workarounds, or should I use it in some other way?

Version I'm using is 3.4

Comment: which version of tinymce are you using?

Comment: thx, that's ok its the new one - looks like i can't help you here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug with tinymce, fixed in https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/8f695d4e84fe77d69af3c490484e4f8775995a79